# How can I tell if a function and class instance method are the same?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

How can I tell if a class instance method and function are the same?

I have a simple class that uses a decorator:

```
@decorate_class
class Hello:

    @decorate_func
    def world(self):
        return
```

And these are my decorators:

```
# A global variable
global_func = None

def decorate_func(func):
    global_func = func
    return func

def decorate_class(clazz):
    print clazz.__dict__["world"] == global_func
    return clazz
```

The above returns `False`, possible because `type(func)` in `decorate_func` is `function`, but in `decorate_class` it is `instancemethod`. But printing both of them gives me:

```
<function world at 0x7f490e59ce60>
```

As in, the same memory address. How do I compare them to know that they are the same function? Is comparing by the memory address safe (and correct)?

Comment: at least `global global_func` is missing in decorate_func()

Comment: Another one of my stupid errors. Thank you so much, sir :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is actually your use of `global_func`.

If you change `decorate_class` to:

```
def decorate_class(clazz):
    print global_func, clazz.__dict__["world"] == global_func
    return clazz
```

You'll see that `global_func` is `None`.

To fix this, explicitly declare `global_func` as `global` in `decorate_func`:

```
def decorate_func(func):
    global global_func
    global_func = func
    return func
```

And everything will work.

This is (basically) because Python assumes that, if you assign to a variable in a function, that variable is assumed to be local to that function, unless it is explicitly declared to be global.

Comment: Well, I got that fixed as J.F. Sebastian mentioned it in the comments and it solved it. But since you mentioned it as an answer I'll mark it as one. Thank you so much for your time :)